# problem while passing credentials in url

Tags: selenium

I m new to selenium. i m nt able to recored the window authentication window while recording.
for that i tried to pass username and password in url bt its also nt working.it s redirect me to some other page.i m using firefox as my browser.
my-method for passing credentials :
http://username:password@servername...is it correct?? if yes then why i m not able pass it.

Is there is any programming way by which i can pass this username and password ???
pls give me the solution...

thnks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Menard (current maintainer of Selenium Grid) has posted a guide to using basic HTTP authentication in Selenium.

> One way to get around this is to embed the user credentials in the URL. Traditionally this has worked well, but newer browsers have disabled that functionality due to the security risks inherently involved. Fortunately, there is another way: send over the authentication credentials in the request header.

Source: http://mogotest.com/blog/2010/06/23/how-to-perform-basic-auth-in-selenium